# When I install ghost with softaculous I get a database error

Tags: node.js, ghost, softaculous

Whenever I try and install Ghost with Softaculous I get the following error.  "The database already exists. Please choose a different name."

Comment: Sounds like the database already exists...

Comment: It doesn't exist though.  It's giving me that error and there are no databases.  It doesn't create one and there were no databases to begin with.

Comment: What about db permissions?